# Change team in Xcode Cloud configure screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

I have an 2 team connected to my Apple Developer account. In one we are planning to launch Xcode Cloud, but then I select Product -> Xcode Cloud -> Create workflow, second team appear and I can't change it.

Have someone found a way to fix this?

[image: Xcode Cloud Beta]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you choose the team while creating workflow in the window like the image link:
[https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/6a4a25c0fa999a0ec9eebb623aff6cb2/Configuring-Your-First-Xcode-Cloud-Workflow-3~dark@2x.png](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/6a4a25c0fa999a0ec9eebb623aff6cb2/Configuring-Your-First-Xcode-Cloud-Workflow-3%7Edark@2x.png)

If you fail

1. Go to your project target -> Signing and capabilities -> Enable automatic manage signing-> Select Team -> Put appropriate bundle identifier -> Press Enter.
2. Go to Product -> Xcode Cloud -> Create workflow -> You should be able to choose the team.

If it still does not work, there may issues with the role of apple ID you are using to connect XCode cloud. It is better to have admin role associated with the account.

Useful References:
i) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/requirements-for-using-xcode-cloud

ii) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-xcode-cloud-for-your-team

Comment: I have automatic signing and admin role enabled in both accounts

Comment: Can you see the teams and their roles in preferences -> Accounts section? If they are not correct, please consider updating your dev certificate and profile using keychain.

Comment: I have both team in this section, in both admin role

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask, did you got this option of selecting team while creating your xcode cloud workflow like the image(link below)? Did you try editing the team using the pen(edit) button? Link to the image: https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/6a4a25c0fa999a0ec9eebb623aff6cb2/Configuring-Your-First-Xcode-Cloud-Workflow-3~dark@2x.png

Comment: That's was helpful. I was confusing by first screen and didn't even tried to pass it :(

Comment: Nice to hear that. You can appreciate my answer as it was helpful for you :)

Comment: I'm not able to get to that screen where we can choose team. Can you please help?

Comment: Go to Product -> Xcode Cloud -> Create workflow -> You should be able to choose the team. @Sanket_B

Comment: Addition for anyone reading this now: simply click "next" on the screen shown in the question. *Then*, and only then, you will land on the screen shown in @MostafaShaminYeasar answer.